# There is any kind of dry-run command using ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby, activerecord, logging

I am doing a ruby script using ActiveRecords.

I have tried using

```
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
```

and now I can see what happens, but there is some way to NOT execute the command, just see that it happened?

Not using rails,rake,etc... Just a ruby script.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: I solve this way: `def createOrPrint(entity,entry)  entity.create(entry) if PERSIST;ap entry;  end`

Answer (score 0):

maybe try this
`gem install pry`

in your script
`require 'pry'`

in your script you can now stop with 
`binding.pry`